# A javascript error occured: object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, onclick

When I press on the button from this code

```
<li><button onclick="add_message_to_card();return false;">Add Text</button></li>
```

I get the following error:

> A javascript error occured: object doesn't support this property or
>   method

The code is on:
http://www.charts4kids.com/pixenate/themes/cardmaker/custom-award-certificates3.php

Comment: Full code? and please make a demo jsfiddle page so this can be relevant to future users when your page changes.

Comment: What does `add_message_to_card` do?

Comment: This is the full code. I don't know how to make a demo jsfiddle page but I will keep this page up. I am making changes on another page.

Comment: I took add_message_to_card  out since it was not in use

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting this error is becasue you are trying to read -1 index of an empty array:

`var font = ff.options[ff.selectedIndex].value;`

When I click on 'Apply' button in your demo page, `ff.options` is an empty collection, and `ff.selectedIndex` is euqal to `-1`.

I think the real issue with your code is error message I see on page-load that says
 `Error loading script: http://www.charts4kids.com/pixenate/fonts.pl`

Try figuring out why your 'Font' dropdown is empty and this will probably fix your error.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer. I have not managed to work out why my font dropdown is empty so I was thinking of getting rid of that option and having a set font that cannot be changed. Would that solve the problem? I tried to that in http://www.charts4kids.com/pixenate/themes/cardmaker/custom-award-certificates6.php but it still didnt solve the problem unless I didnt do it correctly.

Comment: Also, after your message I realized that script: http://www.charts4kids.com/pixenate/fonts.pl was not even on the server. I uploaded it since but it did not help.